# Как не заставлять пользователя авторизироваться после успешной авторизации?

Tags: android, post, auth

Добрый день. Раньше не сталкивался с работой с сетью, но сейчас решил разобраться и появился следующий вопрос. Как не заставлять пользователя вводить логин и пароль после уже успешной авторизации? В приложении есть авторизация. При удачной авторизации приложение получает `Token`(запросом `POST`). Время этого Token'a приблизительно 1 неделя, после этого он обновляется на сервере. Я его помещаю в `БД`. При повторном заходе в приложение у меня стоит превью(экран с картинкой), в котором я проверяю наличие `токена` в `БД` - если он есть, то происходит переход к основному телу приложения, если `токена` в `БД` нет - то происходит переход на экран авторизации. Когда пользователь нажимает кнопку "Выход" в основном теле приложения, `токен` удаляется из БД и  приложение закрывается. Эта реализация конечно работает, но здравый смысл подсказывает, что она неправильна. Подскажите как правильно решить эту задачу

Comment: Увеличить срок жизни токена на сервере, скажем до 1года. В противном случае просто подставлять окно авторизации

Comment: @Chaynik я много где читал, что токен долежн быть действителен около 2 недель, максимум месяц. По поводу подставления окна авторизации, у того же ВК при каждом заходе не открывается же окно авторизации